# Removing selected fields from a CSV file

Tags: csv, batch-file, for-loop, batch-processing, export-to-csv

I have CSV file with 79 fields. But I need only 14 fields from it. So I need to generate a CSV file with these 14 fields. This is daily process ans need to be scheduled. 
I created a batch file to do this with the below command.

```
FOR /f "tokens=1,7,17,18,28,29,31,34,39,61,62,66,71,73 delims=," %%B in (C:\Users\c6372\Desktop\xmltocsv\Fulldata_withheaders.csv) do @echo %%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L,%%M,%%N,%%O>> C:\Users\c6372\Desktop\xmltocsv\Requireddata_withheaders.csv
```

But the problem is, FOR loop in batch files work only till 31 fields. But I have 79 fields. I got to know that if we want to handle more than 31 fields we should use nested for loops. I tried it. But it is not working. Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35592993.txt"
SET "filename2=%destdir%\q35592993out.txt"
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1,7,17,18,28,29,* delims=," %%B in ("%filename1%") do (
 for /f "tokens=2,5,10,29,* delims=," %%I in ("%%H") do (
  for /f "tokens=3,4,8,13,15 delims=," %%N in ("%%M") do (
   echo %%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%N,%%O,%%P,%%Q,%%R>> "%filename2%"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir,`destdir`,`filename1`and`filename2` to suit your circumstances. I used names that suit my system.

I used a file named `q35592993.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

The trick is to use the token `*` which means 'the rest of the line following the last explicitly-mentioned token.`

Comment: @chandrasekhar - Be careful when parsing CSV with FOR /F - It will miscount fields if any field is missing (consecutive commas). Also, FOR /F cannot easily handle commas within fields, plus there are more potential complications. See http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5702 for a utility that allows for robust CSV parsing with batch. Magoo's answer is still good for showing how to handle more than 31 fields of input, even if you use the parseCSV utility.